# Dynamic table in Angular send only changed data to API

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, api, express

I'm trying to achieve the functionality of dynamic table in Angular where data comes from backend first(Express) and then fills the data. I can also add new row to table and send data through it.

I'm able to successfully do it by sending all the data of table to API using formdata. Now I want is only the data which I've changed will be send to API and not the whole data.

This is my table:

[image]

On ngOnInit(), I'm calling API and saving data like `this.collections = res.data`

On Add Row, new row gets added with code:

```
addImage() {
    const obj: Collection = {
      uid: '',
      image: '',
      description: '',
      price: ''
    }
    this.collections.push(obj)
  }
```

On changing the text in input field, I'm using `(input)` property and passing the data to `onInputChange()`

```
onInputChange(text: string, i: string, property: string) {
    this.collections[i][property] = text
 }
```

Now my `this.collections` will have all the data which I'm send via POST API call on Save button i.e., all 3 rows here.

If I don't make any changes still `this.collections` will send that data. What I want is only changed data is send (like I changed only 1 row so only that data is send)

I tried achieving it by creating a new empty `collecctionToAdd` object and add data to it on onInputChange() like this, but since it is on `(input)` event, it keeps on changing for each text field.

```
if(this.collections[i][property] !== text) {
      this.collectionToAdd[i][property] = text
}
```

Any idea or suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the bad thing with this: "I tried achieving it by creating a new empty collecctionToAdd object and add data to it on onInputChange() like this, but since it is on (input) event, it keeps on changing for each text field."?  Every time that your input change you need to update your collecctionToAdd or not ?

Comment: @ManuelPanizzo Yes it keeps on changing. But for every row I need to hold the data and I'm unable to do so. On Save button, it shows only the last row updated

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your "collecctionToAdd" logic.

I guess that you have a ngFor of "this.collections". So you need to do something like `*ngFor="let item of collections; let i = index"` in order to get the index of the element in the original collection an then:

initialize collecctionToAdd as empty Object:

```
private collecctionToAdd = {};
```

Make a function like this:

```
rowChange(text: string; field: string, index: number){
  if(!this.collecctionToAdd[index]){
    // use spread operator in order to keep the original object untouched or not. Remove it if u want
    this.collecctionToAdd[index] = {...this.collecction[index]};
  }
  this.collecctionToAdd[index][field] = text;
}
```

and in your submit function:

```
submit(){
   const rowsToSubmit = []
   for (const key in this.collecctionToAdd) {
         const element: any = this.collecctionToAdd[key];
         rowsToSubmit.push(element);
     }

}
```

NOTE: In the example i used "array syntax" in order to use variables for access and create propeties on object.